# JSF prevent execution of onevent in f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

good day dudes.  does any of you know how we can prevent or change the execution of the onevent for f:ajax?

i have a commandlink with on f:ajax in it.   it's supposed to open up a popup, however, if certain conditions are not met, the popup is not supposed to open.  i would like to know if this is actually possible.

```
<h:commandLink immediate="true">
<f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{myController.executor}" onevent="openDialog"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onclick` attribute of the button. If it returns `false`, then the button's default action won't be invoked.

```
<h:commandButton onclick="return validateForm(this)">
```

Comment: hello balusc, i will need to execute something on the calling method (myController.executor), it will be where the decision to open the popup will be determined.

Comment: @BalusC I need to do that from inside input element like this:
   `<h:inputFile value="#{assessmentAction.file}" id="qFileInput" styleClass="form-control" >
      <f:ajax listener="#{assessmentAction.uploadQuestionEvidence(question)}" render="evidQ_#{question.id}_div msgs" execute="@this"/>
   </h:inputFile>`
Is that possible?